# Is TimeZoneOffset broken?

Tags: date-and-time, entity

I just realized that code like this:

```
TimeZoneOffset[Entity["City",{"SaoPaulo","SaoPaulo","Brazil"}],0,{2020,1,1}]
```

does not return a timezone value anymore. I am quite confident that this has worked up to a few days as I run test-code which contains that snippet (almost) every night.

Similar code is part of the documentation and has been suggested on this site, e.g.:

```
TimeZoneOffset[Entity["City", {"Paris", "IleDeFrance", "France"}]]
TimeZoneOffset[GeoPosition[Entity["ZIPCode", "94402"]["Coordinates"]]]
```

and those examples also don't work for me anymore. Interesting thing is that this is independent of the mathematica-version I use and happens on at least three different machines that I have access to. Does anyone else see these problems except for me? I would consider this a bug...

EDIT (2020-05-26T09:07:28+02:00): Everything seems back to normal right now. The functionality seems to rely on network accessed services and I assume that these had problems last night (that is about 9h ago).

Comment: Yes, something is off. The following example taken straight from the documentation also fails in 12.1 on the cloud: `TimeZoneOffset[Entity["City", {"Paris", "IleDeFrance", "France"}]]`

Comment: ok, just filed a bug report. Will come back here in case I get an answer...

Comment: These all work with v12.1 on my Mac

Answer (score 1):

At least there seem to be a simple workarounds for at least some of the (currently) broken cases:

```
TimeZoneOffset[Entity["City", {"Paris", "IleDeFrance", "France"}]@"TimeZone"]
TimeZoneOffset[First[Entity["ZIPCode", "94402"]@"Cities"]@"TimeZone"]
```

both do still work...

Answer (score 1):

These problems were temporary only and seem to be caused by temporary problems of some service which now works alright again.